# Add Isnull join condition to Azure data factory data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow, azure-synapse-pipeline

I have this sql script : I need to add the "ON UpdatedWOV.Id IS NULL
AND CTH.Id = PT.TranId" to a dataflow. My challenge is specifically how to add "ON UpdatedWOV IS NULL"

please note that there are other join conditions that doesn't require the filter;

```
left join PT
ON UpdatedWOV.Id is null
AND CTH.Id = PT.TranId
left join BT 
on UpdatedWOV.Id is null  
and CTH.Id = BT.TranId
left join etl.PmsRecord 
on CTH.PMSRecordId = PmsRecord.Id 
left join etl.PMSExpenseRecord 
on CTH.PMSExpenseRecordId = PMSExpenseRecord.Id 
left join etl.PMSCommissionRecord 
on CTH.PMSCommissionRecordId = PMSCommissionRecord.Id
```

[image: Data flow screenshot]

I tried to add a filter with the expression "isNull(UpdatedWOV.Id)" in the data flow right before applying the left join "CTH.Id = PT.TranId" but that filters out all the valid records .

Comment: Filter transformation should be applied after join transformation.

Comment: please note that there are other join conditions that doesn't require the filter, I think the use of branch joins may be required but I haven't been successful at that

Comment: Could you share the conditions in detail?

Comment: I updated the conditions on the script above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two branches (for the left joins on PT and BT) from the main data flow
[image]

[image]

and applied my filter on each branch that required "UpdatedWOV.Id" to be null (isNull(UpdatedWOV.Id))

I finally integrated the results of each filter back to the main data flow using the same join conditions;

left join PT
AND CTH.Id = PT.TranId

left join BT
and CTH.Id = BT.TranId

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add   `col1 is not null` in the join transformations condition, you can use cross join and then give the condition as `and(source1@id == source2@id,not(isNull(name)))`. But it doesn't give all the rows of left table. As a workaround, you can use Join transformation for condition with same ids and filter transformation to check if the required field is null. I reproduced this with sample data. In this example, I want to do left join the source1 with source2 based on the `id` column and also to check if `name` is not null.

**Source:1**

```
id,name
1,Pasapugazh
2,Venkat
3,Senthil
4,Virumandi
5,
6,Pari
```

**Source:2**

```
id,age
1,21
2,22
3,32
4,35
5,42
```

- Join transformation is taken and Join type is given as `left outer`.
  Conditions is `source1@id==source2@id`

[image]

**Output of Join:**

[image]

- To remove the rows with null name, filter transformation is taken and condition is given as `not(isNull(name))`

[image]

**Output**

[image]

This removed the rows with null name. By this way, you can expand the joining conditions by join and filter transformations in data flow.

Comment: Hi your solution didn't exactly work as expected, I used another approach

Comment: Share the approach you followed